# Bluetooth LE Advertisment Packet format doesn't match Bluetooth specifications

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm trying to connect to a bluetooth le body scale with my raspberry pi. Because i can't connect to it, whether if i use `python-bluepy` or `gatttool` i tried to get more information and read the advertisment packet with `sudo hcitool lescan --duplicates` & and `sudo hcidump --raw`. I download the Bluetooth Core Specification for versions from 4.0 to 5.1 from bluetooth.com. But the data i get from hcidump does not match the bluetooth specifications exactly. I tried other devices, an iPhone 7, Sony WH-1000MX3 and Oculus Quest. They all send LE packets but all in the (in my opinion) non-standard packet format.
This is a packet i received from the scale (mac a0:91:53:e2:58:db):

```
04 3E 2B 02 01 03 00 DB 58 E2 53 91 A0 1F 02 01 04 03 03 B0 
  FF 0F FF AC A0 DB 58 E2 53 91 A0 A2 AD A0 A3 06 B8 07 09 41
```

The first thing, that i don't understand is the preamble 04. All of my devices use this. But the specification says advertisment packet should have a preamble of 0xAA. And even data packets should have 0xAA or 0x55. But never 0x04. Next thing is the access address. For advertisment should be 0x8E89BED6 but not a single one of my devices use this. I also don't unserstand the PDU header. Lenght is 0. The payload almost matches the specification, but there is a byte after the hardware address (1F) that shouldn't be there. As i said, all of my devices use this format ("wrong" preamble, access address, PDU header, additional byte in Payload). And some devices have only one byte CRC. So i am wondering if i understand something completly wrong. Can anyone explain what kind of package those are or why they don't match the specification?

[BLE Advertisment Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irhwy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in hcitool is the HCI encoded packet, not the original Link Layer packet.

0x04 is the hci packet indicator for HCI Event packet.
The rest is an LE Advertising Report event.

The 0x03 two positions before the address means ADV_NONCONN_IND, which means the device does not accept connections currently. Maybe your scale has a button or something you need to press first to make it connectable.

Comment: Thank you. I see a little bit clearer now. Unfortunatly the scale (Insmart) has no buttons. Maybe i have to sent an advertisment to make the scale accept connections. Is this possible? 
I think this is a little bit offopic to the subject of the questions. Should i start a new questions for this?

Comment: Try to find documentation from the manufacturer. Otherwise we can just speculate.